How can i get all apps in an Azure App service using az cli?
I am trying to get all apps in an Azure App service. Because i want to see which are the orphaned App Service Plans.
I have started with this so far:
   <Login-to-Azure>
  #Get app service plans

 $app_service_plans=$(az appservice plan list --query "[].{Name:name, 
 ResourceGroup:resourceGroup}" --output tsv)

   foreach ($app in $app_service_plans)
{
   $app_count=$(az webapp list --query "[?serverFarmId=='/subscriptions/${subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/${plan_name}'].{Name:name}" --output tsv )

write-host($app_count)
}

Is this the correct approach ? I want to get al the App Service Plans that have no apps and also all Storage Accounts that are orphaned.
How can i do this ?

To get orphaned or unused App service plans you can use below Azure CLI command and I followed Document:
$rith=az graph query -q "
resources
| where type =~ 'microsoft.web/serverfarms'
| where properties.numberOfSites == 0
| project App_Service_Plan_Name=name, Location=location, Res_Grp_Name=resourceGroup 
" | ConvertFrom-Json
$rith.data

Output:

Edit:
I have followed Microsoft-Document and below command worked for me:
Get-AzAppServicePlan | Where-Object {$_.NumberOfSites -eq 0}
Output:


I put the query into powershell and am trying , but takes a long time , is that corect ?

its been 15min and the query hasnt returned. Can we do the same thing with az cli ?

Firstly login to azure using az login, and then run the command. It will work as it worked for me. Try to use the same query as it is and test. Set the subscription and then run the command

exactly what i did , but it takes a long long time and still doesnt come back

So is there a way to do it with plain az cli code ?

This is plain as cli only as graph command

sorry but it does not work, the query never returns

its ok i got it

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
